# SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have 100+ worker threads, which are going to poll database, looking for a new job.

To take a job, a thread need to change status of the bunch of documents from `NEW` to `IN_PROGRESS`, so no other threads can peek the same job.

This can be solved perfectly fine in PostgreSQL with `SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED WHERE status = "NEW"` statement.

Is there a way to do such atomic update in MongoDB for a single document? For a batch?

Comment: for a single document - yes. `findAndModify`. For a batch - not sure, but I think not.

Comment: Read about transactions and atomicity: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits, https://mongodb.com/transactions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) method, which works exactly as you've described for a single document.

For a batch, it's not possible right now, as

> In MongoDB, write operations, e.g. `db.collection.update()`, `db.collection.findAndModify()`, `db.collection.remove()`, **are atomic on the level of a single document**.

It will be possible in MongoDB 4.0 though, with [transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/).

Comment: Although the query may match multiple documents, db.collection.findAndModify() will only select one document to modify.

Comment: How does findAndModify ensure that no other thread is changing the same entry at the same time?

Comment: @kris: I believe it is (and should be) an implementation detail. What is important, is that there's a guarantee of its atomictiy.

Comment: Ok.. i've got an email cron job to test out .. worst case scenario . somebody gets two emails xD

Comment: What if you run `findAndModify` within a transaction, will that `Update` be visible to a concurrent transaction?

Comment: _Yes_, but it may be rolled back. Do check the ["Transactions and Read Concern"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-and-read-concern) section of the MongoDB transactions docs.